# how can I get a URL from an absolute folder path?

Tags: php, url, directory

I have a php function that is moving files for me. It requires absolute paths to place those files (`/Applications/MAMP/HTdocs/mysite/myfolder`)

how can a turn this folder path string into a url (http://mysite.com/myfolder) so that I can create links to the files on the fly?

I do not know necessarily the names of the folders, as the software could be run in many locations.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you need to know server root for such a calculation.
Luclikly, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] contains this path.
So, just subtract server root path from the given path:

```
$path = '/Applications/MAMP/HTdocs/mysite/myfolder';
$approot = substr($path,strlen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']));
```

check if you have a drive letter in the DOCUMENT_ROOT, and correct the code if necessary

Note that adding `http://mysite.com` is unnecessary and useless. just `/myfolder/` is what you really need.

Comment: but is that not then a relative link, where it becomes important to know the location the script is being run from and account for it?

Comment: so I need to adapt that script to include the full path, as I do not have that luxury.

Comment: Don't you have it already? Isn't it your moving files function that require absolute path to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can check for this value: $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];

That is the root of your website. If you have the folder and replace the $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] with the $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] you will get the URL to the folder/file

Answer (score 0):

If mysite folder is within HTdocs then you can access it using http://yourdomain/mysite, (if HTodcs is your home directory)